# BufferedReader method ReadLine() is converting en-dash ("\u2013") to hyphen ("\u002D")

Tags: java, svn, bufferedreader

I have folders in a repository in SVN which have an en-dash ("\u2013") in their names.
I am first calling the "svn list" (in my Windows 7 + UTF-8 encoding) to get the list of the directory.
After that calling BufferedReader readLine(), it reads the text of the list.
The name of the folders being displayed contain a hyphen ("\u002D") instead of the en-dash ("\u2013").

Are there any limitations regarding that ?

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test–ing.xml"));
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } // end main
```

Comment: You might want to post some code. It's rather unclear to me how the svn command and the Java program work together and how you create the `BufferedReader` instance.

Comment: You can try this :
class Test {

 public static void main(String args[]) {

  BufferedReader br = null;

  try {

   String sCurrentLine;

   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test–ing.xml"));
   System.out.println(br.readLine());
   while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
   }

  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   try {
    if (br != null)
     br.close();
   } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 } // end main

Comment: I've added your code to the question. But I still don't understand how it relates to the svn command.

Comment: Thank you Codo.
I am calling the svn command through my java code.
The command used is "svn list".
I am then reading it through readLine().
Hope you got it now ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the problem:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test–ing.xml"));
```

That will use the platform default encoding. You've said that the file is UTF-8-encoded - so you need to specify that you want UTF-8, which means avoiding `FileReader`'s broken API:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
             new FileInputStream("C:\\test–ing.xml"), "UTF-8"));
```

That's assuming the file really *is* valid UTF-8 containing the expected character. You should check that before doing anything else.

Alternatively, given that this is XML, I assume in your real code you're going to use it *as* XML? If so, I would just load it straight from an input stream, and let the XML parser handle the encoding.

Comment: Hi Jon Skeet,
I am using UTF-8 encoding in my java program. My OS is Windows 7.
The issue is not getting resolved.